# Math.sqrt function

Tags: java, joptionpane

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class PredefinedClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        do{
            String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a character:");
            if(input.length() > 1){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Input. Input a character only.");
            }else if(Character.isLetter(input.charAt(0))){
                if(Character.isUpperCase(input.charAt(0))){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The character is an Uppercase letter.");
                }else if(Character.isLowerCase(input.charAt(0))){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The character is a Lowercase letter.");
                }
            }else if(Character.isDigit(input.charAt(0))){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The character is a digit."+
                                                   "\nThe square root of "+input+" is "+Math.sqrt(input.charAt(0)));

            }
        }while(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Try again?[Y/N]","Try again?[Y/N]",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
    }
}
```

Math.sqrt(input.charAt(0)) when i try 9 it's outputting 7.54 which should be 3. Why is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`input.charAt()` returns **the character, not the numeric value of the digit**. This means you're getting `'9'`, as opposed to `9`. The [ASCII value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) of `'9'` is `57`, so you end up taking the square root of that.

Try `Math.sqrt(input.charAt(0) - '0')` instead.

If you want to make your code a little bit more generic, consider using [`Integer.valueOf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) or [`Double.valueOf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) instead of looking at the individual characters.

Comment: @aix may i know why did you add - '0'?

Comment: @jcdavid: I've subtracted `'0'` as this converts the digit represented as a character to its numeric equivalent (i.e. `'0'` becomes `0`, `'1'` becomes `1` and so on).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you use the number nine ASCII code not nine as integer.

```
char c = input.charAt(0);
```

after that you perform the Math.Sqrt(c), now the char is cast to int.

the so the Math.Sqrt get 57 as parameter.

For proper work you should parse the character to Integer like Bala R answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do -

```
Math.sqrt(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(input.charAt(0))));
```

Turn the char to string and parse double from the string.